# Html modal box cannot display full modal body and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying a modal box example from `W3C` to display `python` exceptions, the exception strings are very long, and the modal box body cannot show all of them in one screen and modal footer cannot be displayed too (the browser scroll bar wouldn't scroll down any further), although `overflow: auto;` is set for the entire modal, the code is like,

```js
function show_modal(row, column) {

  var err;
  
  var modal_header = $(".modal-header h2");
  modal_header.text("header_txt");

  var modal_body = $(".modal-body p");
  //                      clear any previous contents
  modal_body.text("");

  var $pre = $("<pre>").html(err);
  modal_body.append($pre);

  var modal_footer = $(".modal-footer h3");
  modal_footer.text("footer_txt");

  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  /*height: 600px; !* Fixed height *!*/
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
}


/*.modal-body {*/


/*padding: 2px 16px;*/


/*}*/

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}

.modal-body {
  width: 90%;
  /*height: auto;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid silver
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>modal header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>modal info</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>modal footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The error messages are too long to fit in the editor, so it is like

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection raise err File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection sock.connect(sa) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 301, in connect raise error(err, strerror(err)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen body=body, headers=headers) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request self.endheaders(body) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output self.send(msg) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send self.connect() File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect conn = self._new_conn() File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fca21d1b550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send timeout=timeout File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 609, in urlopen _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 273, in increment raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8087): Max retries exceeded with url: /ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fca21d1b550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user_name/PycharmProjects/project_service_probe/project_service_probe/project_core_services_probe.py", line 63, in core_services_probe r = self.service_probe(service) File "/home/user_name/PycharmProjects/project_service_probe/project_service_probe/project_core_services_probe.py", line 47, in service_probe self.project_services_config[service]["port"]) File "/home/user_name/PycharmProjects/project_service_probe/project_service_probe/project_core_services_probe.py", line 37, in ping_service return requests.get('http://{}:{}/ping'.format(host, port)) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8087): Max retries exceeded with url: /ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fca21d1b550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

So how to add a scroll bar properly to display the content in the modal body, and also display modal footer when scrolling down the page.

Comment: Put overflow-y: scroll on the modal body and not modal content. Header and footer will remain while body will scroll internally. Give it a max height as well.

Comment: @radiantstatic it doesn't work, I have commented out the `overflow` in `modal` and `modal-content`, set `overflow-y:scroll` in `modal-body`, and yes there is a scroll bar in the `modal-body`, but is not scrollable, and the browser scroll bar is missing,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/radiantstatic/5aeqoa2a/